# JQuery Datepicker is not Returning a Date Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a `JQuery` datepicker object and I am trying to extract the date which is selected within it to work with it. I have read in multiple places that this is the proper way for me to do this:

```
var d = $('datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
```

However, now when I want to say, specifically get the month, I assume that my variable `d` will be a `Date` object so I call `d.getMonth()` but I get an error by doing this which says `d.getMonth is not a function`...

Please let me know what is going on here, and how I will be able to extract the day, month, and year as individual numbers from my datepicker.

Comment: `$('datepicker')` is not a valid selector. Fix that and the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/g8kp15q6/

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I missed that... thank you

Comment: Voting to close. You could save us the trouble and delete it yourself. :)